# Angular/Ionic NG-Class isnt doing anything

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

i have a problem:

im new to ionic/angular and im not able to make ng-class work

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col *ngFor="let field1 of gs.fields; let x = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
            <!-- new row if x % 3 == 0 -->
            <ion-col *ngFor="let field2 of field1; let y = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
              <ion-row>
                <ion-col class="ctr fc tile" *ngFor="let tile of field2; let z = index; trackBy: trackByFn" (click)="playerClick(x,y,z)">
                  <span class="ctr" ng-class="{'player1': tile==1, 'player2' : tile==2}">{{(tile==0)? ' ': ((tile==1)? 'x' : 'o')}}</span>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

```
(click)="playerClick(x,y,z)"
```

Is getting Called in my Service, so i shouldnt be mission any ng-model right?
 I mean `{{(tile==0)? ' ': ((tile==1)? 'x' : 'o')}}` is working, so Angular should have every variable im using right?

**How its shown in the Browser:**

```
<ion-col class="ctr fc tile col">
<span class="ctr" ng-class="{'player1': tile==1, 'player2' : tile==2}">x</span>
</ion-col>
```

I also tried to call a Function inside my Service from ng-style and console log inside the function to test if its called but it wasnt.
Example: `<span class="ctr" ng-style="{'color':getTileColor(tile)}">{{(tile==0)? ' ': ((tile==1)? 'x' : 'o')}}</span>`

Furthermore i would like to force a new row if x%3 == 0
Im thinking of something like (but it isnt working):

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let field1 of gs.fields; let x = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
          <ion-row ng-if "x % 3 == 0">
            <!-- new row if  -->
            <ion-col *ngFor="let field2 of field1; let y = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
              <ion-row>
                <ion-col class="ctr fc tile" *ngFor="let tile of field2; let z = index; trackBy: trackByFn" (click)="playerClick(x,y,z)">
                  <span class="ctr" ng-class="{'player1': tile==1, 'player2' : tile==2}">{{(tile==0)? ' ': ((tile==1)? 'x' : 'o')}}</span>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row ng-if "x % 3 == 0">
        </ion-col>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

^ I put ion-row inside the first nGFor there

```
<ion-row ng-if "x % 3 == 0">
```

[ROWS how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8I3h.png)
[ROWS how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnQfV.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take a moment to look into this to improve and format your question(s): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AhammadaliPK how could i do that? this project needs ionic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you're confusing angular 1 with angular 2.

`ng-style` and `ng-class` are angular 1 syntax

in angular 2 and above the correct way to invoke these directives is:

```
[ngClass]="{'player1': tile==1, 'player2' : tile==2}"
[ngStyle]="{'font-size': fontSize+'px'}"
```

link to [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: ... im so dumb.. thanks! i was using ionic 1 before do you know how to fix the row thing aswell? would you use another grid system?

Comment: i see you're mistyping ng-if as well, should be *ngIf="condition", and you have even a ng-if on the closing tag </ion-row> that is unnecessary. try fixing these

Comment: i to close the ion-row every time x%3==0 && x!=0 otherwise it isnt working, but if i use <ion-row *ngIf="x%3==0 && x!=0"></ion-row *ngIf="x%3==0 && x!=0"> its crashing, if i just use </ion-row> as closing tag it doesnt crash but its not doing what its supposed to do